# Restful Service output format? Which one is better Json ,Xml or ProtoBuf?

Tags: xml, json, rest, protocol-buffers

I have a restful service that will be providing the output, in one of the formats:
1) JSON
2) XML
3) ProtoBuf (Protocol Buffer)

So if the client using the service is mainly rendering the data to the front end (browser,other application and mobile devices), then which of the above is best to use?

Other factors to be considered are:

Maintainability

Performance

Scalability

Comment: Am I crazy or shouldn't a RESTful service allow the client to specify which mime type is best for them?

Comment: But we don't want the restful service layer to decide which format to send based on client requirement.Rather like to go with one format that will fullfill most of our requirements mentioned above.

Comment: check this out... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536893/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-xml-and-json